# Oracle Apex 5 Why is Radio button defaulting when no default is specified

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Radio button which seems to pick a default, even though there is NO default option defined, and the underlying database value is NULL.  No idea what is happening.  I dont want a default ot be Agree...I want nothing to be selected if the underlying database value is NULL.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q4pU.jpg)

[image]

Comment: It doesn't happen for me.  What are the LOV settings for that item, and do you have any dynamic actions that could set it?

Comment: Did you set display extra values to no?